# Java-Server stops working normally

Tags: java, serversocket

I have programmed a little Server with multiple Threads.
After a lot of hours (saidly currently I can't reproduce the problem) the server stops working. My code looks like this.

Thread2:

```
while(true)
{

                System.out.println("Point 1");
                Socket abc = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Point 2");
                connection = true;
}
```

Thread1 waits in a Thread.sleep(1000) loop and checks if connection is true. If so, it starts working, otherwise it prints "waiting". If connection aborts, it sets connection to false.

Now my Mainprogramm connects to the Server. Server prints 
waiting
waiting 
(and so on, till connection is established)
Point 1
Point 2
as it should.

Now after multiple hours of running, my client can still connect, it says connection established (done via clientSocket = new Socket(inetAddress,Integer.parseInt(port)); assumes connection established when this command succeeds without an exception).

After multiple hours of running Thread1 only prints "waiting", "waiting", no matter how often I connect with my client.
I'm stumped with it, because it happens only after multiple hours of running.  Java version is 
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Are there any known issues with this version or where can be the mistake? Any clues how to reproduce the error?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you considered doing a thread dump or running the server in a debugger to get more information about what's going on?

Comment: Now. Problem 1 is that the server runs on another machine as the developing machine. Problem 2 I found no way to pause the thread in the eclipse debugger and then showing me where it right now excecute.s. Is that possible? If so, could you post a link to an instruction for that?

Comment: Now I managed to debug with eclipse. Server now runs on the development machine. Lets hope that the problem occurs again and I am able do debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.
It is sufficient to have that code

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(39999,0,inetAddress);
```

and my Client says connected. There is no need for the a code like

```
Socket neuSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

The whole thread got terminated because of a catch-block out of the while loop. Java is sometimes very confusing. If the thread has stopped with the declaration of the ServerSocket than it should not listen any longer on that socket.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not synchronize the access to `connection` field and it is not a `volatile` field, then one Thread1 might not see that `connection` has changed in Thread2. This is how [Java Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) works.

Comment: I use a third class with a atatic method in the form public static synchronized void setConnection (boolean connection) to avoid what jzou suggest. But even it would be a problem with the other thread not knowing that the connection now exists, it does not print out "Point 1 and Point 2 as it should.